# VS2015 using GIT Merging from Branch to Trunk

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2015, git-branch

I am new to using Git with VS 2015 and come from a TFS background.  I am sure the answer is in my face but I don't know what to do.

I created a branch and now want to merge my changes into the master.  I am using VS 2015, I **do NOT** use nor am familiar with nor can speak logically about **BASH, CLI or any of that command line stuff** :-) I am using the GUI here.  I say this because there are plenty of article on how to accomplish this using the CLI but I don't have the time to engage in this learning endeavor.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

I want to merge **codeCleanup** into master. (see below) what do I do?
[image]

Comment: I tell this to every .Net developer that is new to Git. Use Git Extensions... It is much more robust than the built in tools for visual studio and is a lot easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to your master branch, then select "Merge"

[image: merge]

Then select your working branch and merge that into your current branch (master)
[image]